# Solidity public variable not updated

Tags: solidity

I use truffle for solidity development.

I have this solidity code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract MetaCoin {
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    function MetaCoin() {
        totalSupply = 1000;
    }

    function addOne() public returns (uint256 newTotalSupply)
    {
        totalSupply = totalSupply + 1;
        return totalSupply;
    }
}
```

And this HTML+javascript code to interact with the contract after doing truffle migrate, having testrpc running on port 8545:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_components/web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/truffle-contract/truffle-contract.js"></script>
  <script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var url = "http://localhost:8545";
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
      web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
      web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(url));
    }
    $.getJSON("./contracts/MetaCoin.json", function(MetaCoin_json) {
      var MyContract = TruffleContract( MetaCoin_json );
      MyContract.setProvider(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(url));
      MyContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
        contract=instance;
        return contract.totalSupply.call();
      }).then( function(totalSupply) {
        console.log("totalSupply from init " + totalSupply);
        return contract.addOne.call();
      }).then( function(totalSupplyIncremented) {
        console.log("Value returned " + totalSupplyIncremented);
        return contract.totalSupply.call();
      }).then( function(updatedTotalSupply) {
        console.log("totalSupply after adding one " + updatedTotalSupply);
      });         
    })
  };    
</script>
```

I was expecting to have an output like:

```
totalSupply from init 1000
Value returned 1001
totalSupply after adding one 1001
```

so at the beginning I have a total supply of 1000. I add 1 so I have 1001, and the new total supply is 1001

But instead I got:

```
totalSupply from init 1000
Value returned 1001
totalSupply after adding one 1000
```

Looks like my addOne() method did not update the public totalSupply var. And I can not see why.

Comment: Adding a little more to the answer given below, this is how I extract the actual return-value from the returned `hash` in Python web3: `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash)['logs'][0]['data']`. It is probably similar in Javascript web3. You also need to add `event Event(uint256)` at the top of your contract, and `Event(totalSupply)` right before you `return totalSupply`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're `call`ing `addOne`, but since it modifies state, it needs to be invoked as part of a transaction. Try `addOne.sendTransaction()` instead, but note that what you'll get back is a transaction hash, and you'll have to wait for the transaction to be mined before you can see the updated value.

This blog post of mine may help: https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/13/building-decentralized-apps-with-ethereum-and-javascript/.

Comment: Tried `contract.addOne.sendTransaction()` and `contract.addOne()`. In both cases I got an error "Invalid address"

Comment: You might need `{ from: '<some address you have in MetaMask or unlocked locally>' }`.